# JSF composite component childrens

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

Is there any way using EL to retrieve a children list so i can iterate through it with

```
<ul>
   <ui:repeat value="#{Magic El expression}" var="children" >
      <li>
      <p> #{children.title} *</p>
      </li>
   </ui:repeat>
</ul>
<div>
 <cc:insertChildren />
</div>

* perhaps #{children.attrs.title} I don't know?
```

What I'm trying to do here is create a Tab composite component. I know libraries such as primefaces offer tabview etc. Yet I need to create my own because of extended jquery functionality. Plus I'm working with a specific template.
I need to get the tabs title to create a list for tabs. Tabs are children components is there anyway i can iterate and fetch their attributes? I mean primefaces does that somehow.

If you look at their html markup they create an unordered list with the titles of each children tabview component. How is that implemented?

Comment: May be I didnt understand the question correctly. Can you not just use nested ui:repeat?

Comment: I can, but My question is regarding how to get a composite component's children components. Once I get the list of children components I can iterate through them but how do I get that list?

Answer (score 2):

If the markup you show is inside a composite component (I guess it is), then the following is the expression that will give you access to its children:

`#{component.getCompositeComponentParent(component).children}`

Slightly related question: [In JSF2, how to know if composite component has children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983115/jsf2-has-children/4983235)

Comment: I know that the children has a title attribute, how do I access it? the child.title doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you Composite Component is an instance of : [javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getAttributes)
Try this:

```
    <c:forEach items="#{cc.children}" varStatus="loop" var="child">
      loop[#{loop.index}]: #{child.getAttributes().get('title')}
    </c:forEach>
```

You can easily debug which instance are your JSF variables by printing them to the page like `#{cc}` or `#{component}`

Cheers!