# using insertChildren AND getting child attributes

Tags: jsf, nested, components, children, composite

I am actually trying to create a custom composite table component because h:datatable or p:datatable do not fit my needs. Nevertheless it shall be used like a primefaces datatable. 
After I found [JSF composite component childrens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999720/jsf-composite-component-childrens)
and 
[Expose items of a list while iterating within composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071413/expose-items-of-a-list-while-iterating-within-composite-component) I saw the finish line, but now I got stuck.

My **xhtml**:

```
<h:body>
    <sm:datatable mode="columntoggle" id="mytable" value="#{managerBean.objects}" var="object">
        <sm:column header="KeyHeader" property="key">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.key}"/>    
        </sm:column>
        <sm:column header="ValueHeader" property="value">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.value}"/>    
        </sm:column>
    </sm:datatable>
</h:body>
```

And this is the **datatable composite**:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" />
    <cc:attribute name="mode" />
    <cc:attribute name="var" />
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.List"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <table data-role="table" data-mode="#{cc.attrs.mode}" id="my-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <ui:repeat value="#{component.getCompositeComponentParent(component).children}" var="child">
                    <th>
                        <h:outputText value="#{child.attrs.header}"/>
                    </th>
                </ui:repeat>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="object">
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach items="#{cc.children}" var="child" varStatus="loop">
                        <cc:insertChildren/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</cc:implementation>
```

And that's the **column composite**

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="header" />
    <cc:attribute name="property" />
    <cc:facet name="content"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <td><cc:insertChildren/></td>
</cc:implementation>
```

**thead** works standalone

**tbody** works standalone

Putting them together like above I only get tbody. thead always stays empty Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help in Advance!

Comment: `<table id="my-table` - circumventing JSF's id namespacing. In general: don't do this - you should only set ids to JSF components, not basic HTML tags. In this case, in the composite component, you should have a top level basic HTML tag, but set its id to `#{cc.clientId}`. That way `update="your_comp"` will work.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug, it actually works as designed in mojarra. Using cc:insertChildren moves the children to the parent tag of the cc:insertChildren tag. This problem is equivalent to another problem and has the same solution. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377542/jsf2-composite-components-are-cc-childcount-and-compositeinsertchildren/31619370#31619370).

Basically, you put a `<ui:fragment>` around the `<cc:insertChildren>`, bind that fragment to a property in a FacesComponent bean.

Answer (score 1):

`#{cc.children}` which is equivalent to 
`#{component.getCompositeComponentParent(component).children}` should both work 
but for some reason fail to work in some versions , I guess this part of JSF is still little buggy .

Have you tried

```
 #{cc.getFacets().get('javax.faces.component.COMPOSITE_FACET_NAME').children}
```

Please refer this thread as well,

[In JSF2, how to know if composite component has children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983115/jsf2-has-children/4983235)

Comment: I just tried it but doesn't really work. The only child is the implementation itself. Therefore the output for _#{child}_ is _<table data-role="table" data-mode="#{cc.attrs.mode}" id="my-table"> <thead> <tr>  com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@7f66ff9c  </tr> </thead> <tbody>  com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat@430a14ad  </tbody> </table>_

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. My workaround was to use a `renderFacet`, instead of `insertChildren`.

To iterate over the inserted elements I have used: `#{cc.facets.yourFacetName.children}` and to insert the elements themselves I have used: `<composite:renderFacet name="yourFacetName"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found iterating over children *and* using `<composite:insertChildren />` in the same component to be near impossible. At least in the Mojarra 2.2.6 implementation.

The intermediate facet approach did not work for me either.

Eventually, my solution was to:

1. retain the child component (tab) as is
2. remove all code from the composite:implementation of parent (tab group) component
3. implement `encodeAll()` in the the faces component corresponding to parent

This question is over a year old. Please share if there's a simpler solution in sight.